# Advice to get forward with school assignment needed

Tags: javascript

Hi stackoverflow users,

Im taking basics of javascript at my high-school and I have been having issues with one of the assignments for over a week now.

I have made a "program"/site where you enter two variables name and age. These variables go to two different arrays. AgeArray and NameArray.

I am asked to list all the students that are under 15 years like: John 14, Harry 11, etc.

My issue is that I cant wrap my head around it. If I get all the elements that are under 15 from AgeArray I will still have NameArray that is full of names?

So to get around this I am trying to get the index variables of every element that is under 15 and then get the same element variables from NameArray. But surely there is some way easier way to do this?!? Note, according to the excercise I must have the arrays as are presented here.

Any advice to right direction highly appreciated!Ty.

Edited for code.

```
var AgeArray = [];
var NameArray = [];
var empty = "";
var empty1 = "";
var i;

function addStudent() {
var ageFromPage = document.getelemenetbyid("age").value;
var nameFromPage = document.getelementbyid("name").value;

var age = Number(ageFromPage); //(not sure if this is needed, didnt make any 
difference when debugging)

nameArray.push(nameFromPage);
ageArray.push(age);

for (i = 0; i <= ageArray.length; i++) {
empty = empty + ageArray[i];
empty1 = empty1 + nameArray[i];
}
}
function students() {

//I was stuck here, but will try to move on with help already given. 
//Actually just tried it with the help given and it seems to have solved the 
//problem. CANT BELIEVE IT WAS THAT EASY :/
// - might consist typos - TY for your help! 

}
```

Comment: Can you post the code you have so far?

Comment: I have been working around with the following:

Answer (score 1):

Using two arrays is a really weird way to do it, an array of objects like

```
[
    {name: 'John', age: 14},
    {name: 'Lucy', age: 11}
]
```

would make much more sense. But if your assignment requires it… You can use array index to reference elements from the other array:

```js
var names = ['John', 'Harry', 'Jane', 'Lucy'];
var ages = [14, 15, 12, 16];

ages.forEach(function(age, index) {
 if (age < 15) {
  console.log(names[index] + " " + ages[index]);
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea. Given how you are handling input, your arrays have corresponding indices. So, if you iterate over the length of the arrays with a for loop and find any index where the age is < 15, you can match that index with your name array.

```
for (i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++)
{
  if (ageArray[i] < 15) 
  {
    do something(nameArray[i]);
  }
}
```